# Imposible que una aplicación cargue previamente a hacer operaciones la información contenida en un fichero binario

Tags: java, arraylist, serialización, casting, binary-files

¿qué tal?

Tengo una aplicación de un Banco que, a través de un menú de opciones, gestiona cuentas bancarias y las guarda en un ArrayList. He conseguido que cuando la aplicación se cierre las cuentas bancarias creadas durante la sesión se vuelquen en un fichero binario. No obstante, hay una segunda parte que no consigo. Me piden que cuando la aplicación inicie la ejecución, antes de mostrar el menú, deberá cargar en el ArrayList el contenido del fichero binario.

Muestro cómo tengo las clases Principal y Banco. El error que me muestra es que me dice "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class prog08_tarea.CuentaBancaria (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; prog08_tarea.CuentaBancaria is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at prog08_tarea.Banco.importarCuentas(Banco.java:192)
at prog08_tarea.Principal.main(Principal.java:60)
/Users/victormartinezmacia/Library/Caches/NetBeans/12.0/executor-snippets/run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/victormartinezmacia/Library/Caches/NetBeans/12.0/executor-snippets/run.xml:68: Java returned: 1"

Clase principal

```
package prog08_tarea;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useDelimiter("\n");
        scan.useLocale(Locale.US);

        boolean salir = false;
        int opcion;

        String nombreTitular, apellidosTitular, dniTitular;
        Persona titular;
        String IBAN;
        double saldo;
        int tipoElegido;
        double tipoInteres;
        String listaEntidades;
        double comisionManteni;
        double tipoInteresDescub, maxDescub, comisionDescub;
        String listaCuentas[];
        String infoCuenta;
        double ingreso;

        Banco banco = new Banco();

        try {
            banco.importarCuentas("datoscuentasbancarias.dat");
            
            
            
            
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        

        /                      
        while (!salir) {

            try {

                System.out.println("\n---BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA DEL BANCO. ELIGE UNA OPCIÓN---");
                System.out.println("1. Abrir una nueva cuenta");
                System.out.println("2. Ver un listado de las cuentas disponibles");
                System.out.println("3. Obtener los datos de una cuenta concreta");
                System.out.println("4. Realizar un ingreso en una cuenta");
                System.out.println("5. Retirar efectivo de una cuenta");
                System.out.println("6. Consultar el saldo actual de una cuenta");
                System.out.println("7. Eliminar una cuenta");
                System.out.println("8. Salir de la aplicación");
                opcion = scan.nextInt();

                /**
                 *
                 * El switch permite tomar decisiones según la opción elegida
                 * por el usuario
                 *
                 */
                switch (opcion) {

                    case 1:

                        CuentaBancaria cuenta = null;

                        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del titular");
                        nombreTitular = scan.next();

                        System.out.println("Introduce los apellidos del titular");
                        apellidosTitular = scan.next();

                        System.out.println("Introduce el DNI del titular");
                        dniTitular = scan.next();
                        /**
                         *
                         * Esta condición comprueba que el DNI que se inserta
                         * para una cuenta tiene formato correcto
                         *
                         */
                        if (!dniTitular.matches("^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$")) {
                            throw new Exception("El DNI no tiene un formato correcto\n");
                        }

                        titular = new Persona(nombreTitular, apellidosTitular, dniTitular);

                        System.out.println("Introduce el IBAN");
                        IBAN = scan.next();
                        /**
                         *
                         * Esta condición comprueba que el IBAN que se inserta
                         * para una cuenta tiene formato correcto
                         *
                         */
                        if (!IBAN.matches("^ES[0-9]{20}$")) {
                            throw new Exception("El IBAN introducido no tiene un formato correcto\n");
                        }

                        System.out.println("Introduce el saldo inicial de la cuenta");
                        saldo = scan.nextDouble();

                        System.out.println("Elige qué tipo de cuenta vas a crear");
                        System.out.println("1. Cuenta de ahorro");
                        System.out.println("2. Cuenta corriente personal");
                        System.out.println("3. Cuenta corriente de empresa");
                        tipoElegido = scan.nextInt();

                        /**
                         *
                         * Este switch implementa un submenú para elegir el tipo
                         * de cuenta que se va a crear
                         *
                         */
                        switch (tipoElegido) {

                            case 1:

                                System.out.println("Introduce el tipo de interés");
                                tipoInteres = scan.nextDouble();

                                cuenta = new CuentaAhorro(tipoInteres, titular, saldo, IBAN);

                                break;

                            case 2:

                                System.out.println("Introduce una lista de entidades autorizadas para realizar cobros de recibos");
                                listaEntidades = scan.next();

                                System.out.println("Introduce la comisión de mantenimiento");
                                comisionManteni = scan.nextDouble();

                                cuenta = new CuentaCorrientePersonal(comisionManteni, listaEntidades, titular, saldo, IBAN);

                                break;

                            case 3:

                                System.out.println("Introduce una lista de entidades autorizadas para realizar cobros de recibos");
                                listaEntidades = scan.next();

                                System.out.println("Introduce el tipo de interés por tener un descubierto en la cuenta");
                                tipoInteresDescub = scan.nextDouble();

                                System.out.println("Introduce el máximo descubierto permitido");
                                maxDescub = scan.nextDouble();

                                System.out.println("Introduce la comisión por tener un descubierto");
                                comisionDescub = scan.nextDouble();

                                cuenta = new CuentaCorrienteEmpresa(maxDescub, tipoInteresDescub, comisionDescub, listaEntidades, titular, saldo, IBAN);

                                break;

                            default:
                                throw new Exception("Debes elegir obligatoriamente un tipo de cuenta");

                        }

                        if (banco.abrirCuenta(cuenta)) {

                            System.out.println("Se ha abierto al cuenta satisfactoriamente");

                        } else {

                            System.out.println("Error. La cuenta no se ha creado");

                        }

                        break;

                    case 2:

                        listaCuentas = banco.listadoCuentas();
                        for (int i = 0; i < listaCuentas.length; i++) {

                            System.out.println(listaCuentas[i]);

                        }
                        
                        if (listaCuentas.length == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Todavía no hay cuentas");
                        }

                        break;

                    case 3:

                        System.out.println("Introduce el IBAN");
                        IBAN = scan.next();

                        infoCuenta = banco.informacionCuenta(IBAN);
                        if (infoCuenta != null) {

                            System.out.println(infoCuenta);

                        } else {

                            System.out.println("No existe ninguna cuenta con el IBAN especificado");

                        }

                        break;

                    case 4:

                        System.out.println("Introduce el IBAN");
                        IBAN = scan.next();

                        System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad que quieres insertar");
                        ingreso = scan.nextDouble();

                        if (banco.ingresoCuenta(IBAN, ingreso)) {

                            System.out.println("El ingreso se hizo correctamente");

                        } else {

                            System.out.println("El ingreso no se pudo realizar");

                        }

                        break;

                    case 5:

                        System.out.println("Introduce el IBAN");
                        IBAN = scan.next();

                        System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad que quieres retirar de la cuenta");
                        ingreso = scan.nextDouble();

                        if (banco.retiradaCuenta(IBAN, ingreso)) {

                            System.out.println("La retirada se hizo correctamente");

                        } else {

                            System.out.println("La retirada no se pudo realizar");

                        }

                        break;

                    case 6:

                        System.out.println("Introduce el IBAN");
                        IBAN = scan.next();

                        saldo = banco.obtenerSaldo(IBAN);
                        if (saldo != -1) {

                            System.out.println("El saldo es: " + saldo);

                        } else {

                            System.out.println("No existe ninguna cuenta con el IBAN especificado");

                        }

                        break;

                    case 7:

                        System.out.println("Introduce el IBAN");
                        IBAN = scan.next();

                        if (banco.eliminarCuenta(IBAN)) {

                            System.out.println("La cuenta se eliminó correctamente");

                        } else {

                            System.out.println("La cuenta no se puede eliminar");

                        }

                        break;

                    case 8:
                                              
                        salir = true;                                                                      
                        System.out.println("\nSaliste del programa");
                        
                        banco.exportarCuentas();
                        
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("\nDebes elegir una opción válida");
                        break;

                }

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                scan.next();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Clase Banco

```
package prog08_tarea;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Banco implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<CuentaBancaria> cuentas;

    /* Utilizo un ArrayList porque anteriormente tenía un array, y con el ArrayList lo guardo de forma similar 
    pero con capacidad dinámica. No necesito el doble enlace de las LinkedList porque no voy a ir hacia adelante 
    o atrás con los elementos, sino acceder a ellos a través de un IBAN */
    public Banco() {
        this.cuentas = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean abrirCuenta(CuentaBancaria c) {

        CuentaBancaria existe = this.buscarCuenta(c.getIBAN());

        if (existe != null) {

            System.out.println("La cuenta ya existe\n");
            return false;

        }

        this.cuentas.add(c);
        return true;

    }

    public String[] listadoCuentas() {

        String[] infoCuentas = new String[this.cuentas.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < infoCuentas.length; i++) {

            infoCuentas[i] = this.cuentas.get(i).devolverInfoString();

        }

        return infoCuentas;

    }

    public String informacionCuenta(String IBAN) {

        CuentaBancaria c = this.buscarCuenta(IBAN);

        if (c != null) {

            return c.devolverInfoString();

        } else {

            return null;

        }

    }

    public boolean ingresoCuenta(String IBAN, double cantidadIngresar) {

        CuentaBancaria c = this.buscarCuenta(IBAN);

        if (c != null) {

            c.setSaldo(c.getSaldo() + cantidadIngresar);
            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }

    public boolean retiradaCuenta(String IBAN, double cantidadIngresar) {

        CuentaBancaria c = this.buscarCuenta(IBAN);

        if (c != null) {

            if ((c.getSaldo() - cantidadIngresar) >= 0) {

                c.setSaldo(c.getSaldo() - cantidadIngresar);
                return true;

            } else {

                return false;

            }

        }

        return false;

    }

    public double obtenerSaldo(String IBAN) {

        CuentaBancaria c = this.buscarCuenta(IBAN);

        if (c != null) {

            return c.getSaldo();

        } else {

            return -1;

        }

    }

    public boolean eliminarCuenta(String IBAN) {

        CuentaBancaria c = this.buscarCuenta(IBAN);

        if (c != null) {

            for (CuentaBancaria cAux : this.cuentas) {

                if (cAux.getIBAN().equals(IBAN) && cAux.getSaldo() == 0) {
                    this.cuentas.remove(cAux);
                    return true;

                }

            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void exportarCuentas() {

        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("datoscuentasbancarias.dat"))) {

            for (CuentaBancaria c : this.cuentas) {
                oos.writeObject(c.devolverInfoString());   
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Banco.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void importarCuentas(String fichero) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fichero))) {
            
            
            while (true) {
                
                CuentaBancaria aux = null;                
                do {                    
                    aux = (CuentaBancaria) ois.readObject();
                    if (aux != null) {
                        this.cuentas.add(aux);
                    }                    
                } while (aux != null);
                                                                              
            }
            
        } catch (EOFException ex) {}
        

    }

    private CuentaBancaria buscarCuenta(String IBAN) {

        for (CuentaBancaria c : this.cuentas) {

            if (c.getIBAN().equals(IBAN)) { //aplicamos un foreach
                return c;
            }

        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con el siguiente código en la clase principal. Lo que hace es leer el archivo e ir creando cuentas bancarias con el método abrirCuenta

```
public static void cargarFichero(Banco banco) {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("datoscuentasbancarias.dat");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(file);
        int numCuentas = ois.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCuentas; i++) {
            CuentaBancaria cuenta = (CuentaBancaria) ois.readObject();
            banco.abrirCuenta(cuenta);
        }
        ois.close();
        file.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al leer el fichero");
    }
}
```